# stopping an IntentService causes null pointer execption

Tags: android

The code for my IntentService class is:

```
public class UdpSendService extends IntentService {
//...variable declarations
public UdpSendService() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super("UdpService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    host = intent.getStringExtra("host");
    port = intent.getIntExtra("port", 4000);
    pType= intent.getIntExtra("pType", 0);
    delay = intent.getIntExtra("delay", 0);
    msg= intent.getStringExtra("msg");
    broadcastIntent = new Intent(UdpResponseReceiver.ACTION_RESP);
    broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    try {
        addr = InetAddress.getByName(host);
        // addr=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        socket = new DatagramSocket();
        // socket.connect(addr,port);

        System.out.println("\nSocket Connected");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("\nConnection failed");
        return;
    }

    send=true;
    switch (pType) {
    case 0:
        while (send) {
            sendPacket(msg);
        }
    case 1:
        // Float f = new Float(delayField.getString());
        // for(int i=0;i<2000;i++)
        while (send) {
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(delay);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            sendPacket(msg);
        }
        // break;
    case 2:
        // for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
        while (send) {
            int u = want(30);
            // int e=(int)Math.floor(-1*log(u)/(log((float)2.718)*2));
            // System.out.println(e);
            String data1 = "";
            while ((u--) > 0)
                data1 = data1 + msg;
            sendPacket(data1);
        }
        // break;
    case 3:
        //float f2 = Float.parseFloat(delayField.getText().toString());
        // for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
        while (send) {
            int u = want(30);
            // int e=(int)Math.floor(-1*log(u)/(log((float)2.718)*2));
            System.out.println(u);
            String data1 = "";
            while ((u--) > 0)
                data1 = data1 + msg;
            System.out.println("data length :" + data1.length());
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(delay);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            sendPacket(data1);
        }

    }
}
public void onDestroy(){

    super.onDestroy();
    send=false;
    socket.close();
    socket=null;

}
void sendPacket(String text) {

    try {
        System.out.println("\nClient:: Sending packet: " + " to " + addr
                + port);
        byte[] data = text.getBytes();
        spacket = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, addr, port);
        socket.send(spacket);
        String resultTxt="Sent Packet at:"+DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yy h:mmaa", System.currentTimeMillis());
        broadcastIntent.putExtra(PARAM_OUT_MSG, resultTxt);
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error:" + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        // e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
}
}
```

I stop the service from the activity by calling

```
stopService(udpServiceIntent); //I start the service using the same intent
```

the logcat shows:

```
01-14 15:53:41.446: W/System.err(1176): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-14 15:53:41.456: W/System.err(1176):     at com.example.udpmessageclient.UdpService.sendPacket(UdpService.java:123)
01-14 15:53:41.466: W/System.err(1176):     at com.example.udpmessageclient.UdpService.onHandleIntent(UdpService.java:74)
01-14 15:53:41.466: W/System.err(1176):     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
01-14 15:53:41.466: W/System.err(1176):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-14 15:53:41.466: W/System.err(1176):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-14 15:53:41.476: W/System.err(1176):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

As per my understanding the program still tries to execute

```
socket.send(spacket);
```

even after the service is stopped and the socket is closed. How can this be avoided? What is the correct way to stop a service and release resources?

Comment: you can test the socket before using it.

Comment: thanks.I shall try that. But is there any better way? I already have a flag variable **send** which when set to false exits from the loop. I am setting it to false in the onDestroy() method of the IntentService.

Comment: thanks njzk2, your suggestion solved the error.

Comment: regarding your previous comment, you test send before the wait, therefore there can be a delay between setting it to false and actually testing it. you could resolve this by calling sendPacket before sleep.

Comment: @njzk2 : actually, except for `case 0`, in all other cases the packet is sent with some delay, hence the `sleep` statement is added.So maybe I could resolve this by testing `send` after `sleep` and before the `sendPacket` statement.

Comment: yes. but remember that onHandleIntent and onDestroy are not on the same thread, so you should synchronize the operations on socket, to make sure one does not close it when you are about to access it

Comment: I agree with you.Today I added a new IntentService to my application, which receives packets from the same socket. When I try to stop the service I get a SocketException since the socket is closed from another thread, when a thread is still waiting to receive a packet from it.